# numeric variable in egrep regular expression bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

So I am trying to make a script that contains egrep and accepts a numeric variable

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$1
list="egrep "^.{$var}$ /usr/share/dict/words"
cat list
```

For example, if var is 5, I would like this script to print out every line with 5 characters. For some reason the script does not do that. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to write the result to the file `list`?

Comment: Avoid the usage of `egrep`. This is depricated. Make use of `grep -E` instead. (see `man grep`)

Comment: Copy/paste your code to http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues it tells you about, and then let us know if you still have a problem you need help with.

Answer (score 3):

Your script doesn't work because there are several problems with these lines:

```
list="egrep "^.{$var}$ /usr/share/dict/words"
cat list
```

1. The first line isn't complete, it's missing a closing quote,
2. Even if you fixed it, you're assigning a literal string to `list`, not the output of a command,
3. RE and filename should be separated
4. `cat` doesn't print a variable's content, `echo` does that.

So:

```
#!/bin/bash
var="$1"
list="$(egrep '^.{'"$var"'}$' /usr/share/dict/words)"
echo "$list"
```

should work.

Or even better, you can use just an [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) command:

```
awk 'length==5' /usr/share/dict/words
```

with `$1` or any other variable:

```
awk -v n="$1" 'length==n' /usr/share/dict/words
```